# How to read and update based on item $id in Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I cannot figure out how to read and update using Firebase based on id. In this case, I have a list of todos, I want to find the first item based its $id, and then change `comple` to true.

```
todos
  -Ke0JWl9xy5sZvT55hfE
       Complete:  false
       Created_at: 1488228401479
       Description: "123"
       Priority: "high"
  -Ke0Ms_LnsO-TSwQZLcZaddclose
  -Ke0MuWCLkX29XWYyPBM
  -Ke0MwKOrjpDm9rj6L28
  -Ke0NCmpM3_dTPtY9jVb
```

JS

```
(function() {
  function Todo($firebaseArray) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("todos");
    var todos = $firebaseArray(ref);

    Todo.todos = todos;
    Todo.updateToDo = function(todo){
      console.log(todos)

      console.log(todos[todo['$id']])
    };
    return Todo;
  }

  angular
    .module('blocitoff')
    .factory('Todo', ['$firebaseArray', Todo]);
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a much simpler approach:

```
(function() {
  function Todo($firebaseArray) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("todos");
    var todos = $firebaseArray(ref);

    Todo.todos = todos;
    Todo.updateToDo = function(todo){
      ref.child(todo['$id']).update({ completed: true });
    };
    return Todo;
  }

  angular
    .module('blocitoff')
    .factory('Todo', ['$firebaseArray', Todo]);
})();
```

The `update()` call here uses the Firebase JavaScript SDK. But since AngularFire is built on top of that, they interoperate perfectly anyway.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. This is kind of related, so how do I return of that object based on `$id`? When I try to use `console.log(ref.child(todo['$id']));`, it just returns `U {u: Te, path: L, m: ee, Nc: false, then: undefined…}`. My goal here is to get to the `Description`.

Comment: That code just sets up a reference. It doesn't retrieve any value yet. To learn how to access the database from JavaScript without AngularFire, I recommend: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start